# MYSQL WITH LIKE, OR, AND, gives all results

Tags: php, mysql

i'm pulling my hair here trying to get this one to work.

This is my code:

```
     SELECT a1.*
       , t2.`name` AS project_name
       , t2.`id` AS project_id   
       , u2.`fname` AS fname
    , u2.`lname` AS lname
    , u2.`color` AS color 
    , u2.`id` AS user_id 
    , u3.`fname` AS creatorfname
    , u3.`lname` AS creatorlname

    FROM `activities` AS a1 
    LEFT JOIN `projects` AS t2 ON a1.`projectid`=t2.`id`
    LEFT JOIN `users` AS u2 ON a1.`userid`=u2.`id` 
    LEFT JOIN `users` AS u3 ON a1.`creatorid`=u3.`id` 
    LEFT JOIN `organisations` AS o1 ON u2.`orgid`=o1.`id` WHERE   
          o1.`id`=:orgid AND a1.`active`=1  OR a1.`postarea` LIKE '%newyork%' 
             OR a1.`streetname` LIKE '%newyork%' 
             OR a1.`companyname` LIKE '%newyork%' 
             OR a1.`postarea` LIKE '%newyork%' 
             OR a1.`orgnumber` LIKE '%newyork%' 
             OR a1.`postcode` LIKE '%newyork%' 
             OR a1.`homepage` LIKE '%newyork%' 
             OR a1.`phone1` LIKE '%newyork%' 
             OR a1.`phone2` LIKE '%newyork%' 
             OR a1.`phoneswitch` LIKE '%newyork%' 
             OR a1.`status` LIKE '%newyork%' 
             OR a1.`turnovermin` LIKE '%newyork%' 
             OR a1.`turnovermax` LIKE '%newyork%' 
             OR a1.`description` LIKE '%newyork%' 
             OR a1.`comment` LIKE '%newyork%'
             OR a1.`email` LIKE '%newyork%' AND a1.`projectid`=:projectid     
            AND a1.`userid`=:userid AND a1.`date`>=:datefrom AND 
           a1.`date`<=:dateto ORDER BY a1.`date` DESC
```

The problem is, I get every result based on the OR LIKE statements.
I use PDO class therefore its for example :orgid. It should consider all statements and criterias. I have tried ( ) around AND...and so on but without any results.

Would appreciate some help.

Comment: `WHERE o1.\`id\`=:orgid AND (BUNCH OF ORs) AND a1.\`projectid\`=:projectid AND a1.\`userid\`=:userid AND a1.\`date\`>=:datefrom AND a1.\`date\`<=:dateto`

Comment: You need to learn about logical parentheses.

Comment: You have to tell us what you want to have as result. Your statement looks pretty weird to me and too much complicated. Why the hell are you querying "New York" 10 times??

Comment: @etalon11 A universal search bar that searches within multiple fields to get the user the most relevant result. I think OP is trying to avoid the fukky search tools which all libraries seem to use when searching for scholarly articles.

Comment: etalon its searchword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `()` around `OR`s, `AND` operator has higher priority thus is applied before `OR`.

```
 SELECT a1.*
   , t2.`name` AS project_name
   , t2.`id` AS project_id   
   , u2.`fname` AS fname
, u2.`lname` AS lname
, u2.`color` AS color 
, u2.`id` AS user_id 
, u3.`fname` AS creatorfname
, u3.`lname` AS creatorlname

FROM `activities` AS a1 
LEFT JOIN `projects` AS t2 ON a1.`projectid`=t2.`id`
LEFT JOIN `users` AS u2 ON a1.`userid`=u2.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `users` AS u3 ON a1.`creatorid`=u3.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `organisations` AS o1 ON u2.`orgid`=o1.`id`
WHERE   
      o1.`id`=:orgid AND a1.`active`=1  AND
        (   a1.`postarea` LIKE '%newyork%' 
         OR a1.`streetname` LIKE '%newyork%' 
         OR a1.`companyname` LIKE '%newyork%' 
         OR a1.`postarea` LIKE '%newyork%' 
         OR a1.`orgnumber` LIKE '%newyork%' 
         OR a1.`postcode` LIKE '%newyork%' 
         OR a1.`homepage` LIKE '%newyork%' 
         OR a1.`phone1` LIKE '%newyork%' 
         OR a1.`phone2` LIKE '%newyork%' 
         OR a1.`phoneswitch` LIKE '%newyork%' 
         OR a1.`status` LIKE '%newyork%' 
         OR a1.`turnovermin` LIKE '%newyork%' 
         OR a1.`turnovermax` LIKE '%newyork%' 
         OR a1.`description` LIKE '%newyork%' 
         OR a1.`comment` LIKE '%newyork%'
         OR a1.`email` LIKE '%newyork%'
       )
        AND a1.`projectid`=:projectid     
        AND a1.`userid`=:userid AND a1.`date`>=:datefrom AND 
       a1.`date`<=:dateto ORDER BY a1.`date` DESC
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! You really saved my night :D That one worked perfectly. I will have a look at these stuff with parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

You need to learn about logical parentheses.

`a AND b OR c OR d` means logic contamination. Parentheses tell a processor which operations to carry out first, rather than ranking each equally:

`a AND (b OR c)` - true if A is true and B or C are also true

`(a AND b) OR c` - true if A and B are true, or, regardless of them, if C is true instead